# Why do dead batteries bounce?

Tags: everyday-life

It seems like you can test if an Alkaline battery is empty by just dropping it on the floor. If it's empty, it will bounce and fall down. Why is that?

Here is a video of it:

[image: Picture: Used batteries tend to bounce and fall down]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See  [this](http://www.princeton.edu/main/news/archive/S42/72/95S25/index.xml?section=topstories) research conducted in Princeton.

To summarize their research, they found that it's related to how batteries generate electricity.
It's generated by a chemical reaction inside the batteries, as zinc turns to zinc oxide.
The zinc oxide starts to cover the outside of the battery, and is a bouncier material, and this creates the bounce.
(Also, in many patents, zinc oxide is used to make golf balls bounce more, so this is hardly surprising)